# pyodbc+mssql connection possible but query fails

Tags: sql-server, docker, sqlalchemy, jupyter, pyodbc

The following code is running into a Docker container. I have a connection specified as follow which is working as I could make a simple query based on it.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:pw@hostname?driver_name")
con_xpf = engine.connect()
con_xpf.execute("use db_name;")
```

After that I create a sqlite3 DB and connect to it:

```
DBNAME = "data/NEWDB.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(DBNAME)
tbllist = ["AAAAA","BBBBBBBB","CCCCCCCCC","DDDDDDDDD","EEEEEEEEE"
           "FFFFFFFFF","GGGGGGGGG","HHHHHH","IIIIIIIII"]
chunksizes = [500000,800000,500000,1000000,500000,500000,500000,900000,500000]
```

The problem start from here when I try to run the following code to query from the first DB to write into the sqlite DB:

```
def loads_data_from_xpf(tbllist,chunksizes) :
    for tbl,chunksize in zip(tbllist,chunksizes) :
        cnt = 0
        maxcnt = math.ceil(pd.read_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM x.{}".format(tbl),con_xpf).CNT[0]/chunksize)
        with tqdm(range(maxcnt)) as pbar:
            for chunk in pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM x.{} A".format(tbl),con_xpf,chunksize=chunksize) :
                chunk.to_sql(tbl,con,if_exists="append")
                pbar.update()
                
loads_data_from_xpf(tbllist,chunksizes)
```

I got the following error:

```
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x71 (113) (SQLGetData)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Could the problem be because of the size of the query? Do you see any error somewhere? I am stuck for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am now able to see the sqlite DB file updating meaning data are pushed into it. But I have the following error which is because of the Jupyter Kernel. Help please

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 841, in async_execute_cell
    exec_reply = await self.task_poll_for_reply
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

nbclient.exceptions.DeadKernelError: Kernel died
```

Comment: Does it help if you avoid the `USE …` by putting the database name in the connection URI? `mssql+pyodbc://username:pw@hostname/db_name?driver=driver_name`

Comment: @GordThompson I tried without success. Also would like to note that this disconnect my container everytime I try and I have to re launch Docker as it freeze.